# How to check for changes in a XML file?

Tags: java, xml, hash

I want to make sure 2 XML files are the same, and the 2 options I see are.
 1. Get the XML to have a last modification date with time, and check that is the same. Problem is that someone may forget to change it and then it is useless.
 2. Create a hashcode of the xml file/structure.

I use a build in library in java, but the hash implementation can change from run to run which is not helpful

```
File model = new File(fileLocation);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(model);
doc.getHash();
```

is there an easy way to do this, and hopefully without importing another library.

Comment: I can read to different question out of this: Eith you want to check if the *file content* differs (then simply hash the file) or you want to check if the actual XML-structure changed (so swapping the order of to elements may not result in a difference). Which one is it?

Comment: In my app, which uses "XML hashing", I hash (using a stream) over a DOM in a well-defined order - that is, I sort elements alphabetically and descend depth-first and for each element I sort values alphabetically. It Works For Me (TM).

Comment: I think the first choice, if both files are identical. Second would be great, but I think its too complicated and in my case not necessary.

Comment: Note that two different objects can have the same hash code

Comment: Wouldn't it be highly unlikely? Or would it be because changes could be small?

Comment: @AndreuAlcon That usually only applies when talking about `hashCode` or similar. The chances of collisions with MD5 (or better, SHA-1 or newer) are so improbable that it can generally be discounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Thurau pointed out, it depends, whether you want to check if the files are identical, or if the XML content is identical. This answer is only for the first case, when you want to know if two files are identical, i think that was your question because you suggested a hash value.

In this case building a hash is not a good choice, you can solve it easier like this:

1. Check whether the file sizes are the same, if not they are not identical.
2. Open a stream of both files.
3. Just loop through the streams and stop by the first difference.
4. If no differences where found, they are identical.

So why not calculating a hash value? You have to read the whole file anyway to calculate a hash, so when you compare the streams you can forgo the calculation, and you can stop by the first difference. Parsing the file to a DOM model will also have the same disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

Will sorting the file and comparing help?

In case of libraries, 
You can try [diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/) .

[XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) has a [diff](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/Diff.html) feature